# What pieces of equipment are safe to sell?

Tags: final-fantasy-7

One thing that annoys me about Final Fantasy 7 (and 6) is that it's very difficult to sell items. Well, I mean, selling them is pretty easy, but the selling screens give you all sorts of numbers, and *none of them are about the stats of what you're selling.*

> [image: Chrono Trigger's sell items screen]       [image: Final Fantasy 7's sell items screen]
>
> <sub>*One of those sell screens does not suck. Guess which!*</sub>

The only point in holding onto old equipment I can come up with is "unequipping" people's weapon and defense slots so you can always have the best gear available for your current party, and very early game equipment will do the job nicely. People joining — and *leaving* — your party also can likely throw you curveballs, but other than that...

So, how can I determine what pieces of inventory are safe to sell?

Comment: I personally have found that there isn't a point to ever sell anything. I can't remember the last playthrough I sold something. For what do you feel do you need cash for?

Comment: @Ender ALL the things

Comment: For what its worth, (keep in mind I've played this game from start to finish more times than I can remember) that normal mediocre RPG grinding should give you more than enough cash for almost anything you need. Also, a tip, your #1 priority for cash is to master your **ALL** materias as fast as possible, I forget exactly how much Master ALLs sell for but it's astronomically high. I beleive it's either in the 100,000 or 1,000,000 range.

Comment: Due to how early you get your first ALLs, its very reaslitic to have at least one if not two or three mastered rather early.

Comment: @Ender Yeah, a master All goes for 1,400,000 gil

Answer (score 11):

I've collected information about [all pieces of armor in the game](http://finalfantasy.wikia.com/wiki/List_of_Final_Fantasy_VII_Armor) and fed it [to a little bit of Python 3](https://gist.github.com/badp/11375630) which gives me this chart, where the arrows mean " → is better in every possible way than →". This pushes better items at the top and worse items at the bottom.

> ```
>                    (better armor)
> ```
>
> [image]
>
> ```
>                                                   (worse armor)
> ```
>
> **[Click for bigger, searchable version](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/1164414/SO/FF7%20armor%20outdating.svg)**
>
> <sup>Footnotes: **(1)** Tifa, Aeris, and Yuffie only **(2)** Cloud, Barret, Red XIII, Cait Sith, Vincent, and Cid only.</sup>

How to read this chart:

- If `X → Y`, it means that `X` is better in every possible way than `Y`.
- If `X → Y → Z`, it means that:

  - `X` is better in every possible way than `Y`
  - `Y` is better in every possible way than `Z` *and*
  - `X` is *also* better in every possible way than `Z` (this is necessary to make the chart readable, or you get [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WLdM3.jpg)).
- If an item is not in the diagram at all, then it's neither better or worse than any other item, so... just don't sell it.
- In all versions of Final Fantasy 7 prior to the 2012 PC re-releases, [the magic defense stat on all armor is purely cosmetic: it only appears to have an effect on the equip screen.](http://finalfantasy.wikia.com/wiki/Magic_Defense_Bug) If you are playing the Steam or Square Enix store versions of FF7, ignore the grey dashed arrows.

In other words, if you can make a path following the arrows from an armor to another, then that other armor is worse than the first in every possible way. So, for example, the Dragon Armlet and the Gold Armlet are both better than the Shinra Beta, but the Dragon Armlet has elemental damage halving whereas the Gold Armlet has better stats in general, so neither is perfectly better than the other. When you acquire the Diamond Bangle, therefore, you can safely sell the Silver Armlet but not the Dragon Armlet.

---

What about weapons? The results are somewhat less interesting because all weapons can only be used by one character, and some characters have different guns dealing damage of different elements, so this splits the diagram quite considerably. Here they are, nonetheless, this time from left (best) to right (worst):

> ```
> (better weapons)                     (worse weapons)
> ```
>
> [image]
>
> **[Click for bigger, searchable version](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/1164414/SO/FF7%20weapon%20outdating.svg)**

Answer (score 5):

I tend to follow a rather conservative rule of **"if I bought it at a store, and that item is at least 2 store-grade-items out of date"** then I consider it safe to sell.  Additionally, I don't tend to sell unless I need cash for something.

So for instance you go to NPCville and you buy a shiny Bronze Sword, and then you visit NPCtowne and they're selling a Steel Sword.  I probably wouldn't even buy the Steel Sword in this case, and I'd probably not sell the Bronze Sword if I did.  But once I reach NPCtopia, and they're selling a Magic Sworde, but I can't afford it, I'll sell off my Bronze Swords to pay for it.

In FF7 in particular, I'd hang on to things that have a lot of Materia Slots or high Materia growth if you plan to grind some of the more difficult Materia up to their "master" states.  Even if the weapon sucks, you're still getting bonus AP out of them.  Everything else I'd sell as per my plan above.

Comment: Yeah, there's a lot of "ifs" and "buts" that make it hard to say "this is now garbage" but there's certainly plenty of garbage in my inventory already and I've not even reached "CD 2"