# What pieces of eqipment are safe to sell?

Tags: final-fantasy-6

Just like Final Fantasy 7, the sell screen for Final Fantasy 6 is perhaps enragingly... lacking.

> [image: Buy screen]  [image: Sell screen]
>
> <sup>There's a pane for character portraits *on both the buy and the sell screen*, but the sell screen's is inexplicably empty. Sigh.</sup>

Given that you can unequip party members in this game through the convenient "Remove all" button on the Equip screen, the only reason for holding onto old stuff is if you somehow like to scroll through pages of junk.

The selling situation on FF6 is especially difficult because most of the items are only available for a subset of characters. Moreover, for most of the game most of your party will be unequipped, so even if the sell screen *had* character portaits, it'd be kinda useless.

Finally, for most of the game you'll only need equipment for 4 people — until you hit the Narshe battle and the end game. That said, the Narshe battle is kind of early on, whereas by the end game you should have enough gil to buy and obtain top-notch equipment for your party anyway.

So... what items can be sold safely in Final Fantasy 6?

Answer (score 4):

[Again](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/166057/23), with the help of the [Final Fantasy Wikia](http://finalfantasy.wikia.com/wiki/List_of_Final_Fantasy_VI_Armor) and [Python 3 love](https://gist.github.com/badp/11375630), I have some chart goodness for you, dear reader. The arrows here mean " → is better in every possible way than →". This pushes better items to the left and worse items to the right.

Keep in mind that "better in every possible way than" means that *all* of these are true:

- Each individual stat on the item is equal or better
- It's got the same or more buffs — under the assumption that stamina buffs are welcome. (Higher stamina means better defense against instant death and faster regeneration, *but* it also increases the rate at which poison and sap drain your HP.)
- It's got equal or no worse weaknesses. For example, the Ice and Flame shields are nice, but they're the only ones with elemental attack weaknesses, so they only get to be better than the Cursed Shield.
- It's available for at least the same group of characters (additions welcome).
- It fits in the same equipment slot. (Duh.)

In other words, for the purpose of this post, an item that grants 7 bonus points of magic is *not* better in every possible way than an item granting 1 magic *and* 1 speed.

**Unfortunately** there is a perhaps crucial piece of information missing: this chart makes the assumption that you can get arbitrarily many of each item, and that's not necessarily true; for example, you can only get one Paladin's Shield ever. I suppose that unique items probably shouldn't be on the chart to begin with?

One final caveat: the Cursed Shield and the Excalipoor appear *both* at the bottom *and* at the top of their respective food chains — you just need to unlock their true potential... somehow ;)

If you aren't too convinced that this post is useless yet, here's the armor chart in all its glory:

> [image]
>
> [**Click for the bigger, searchable version**](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/1164414/SO/FF6%20armor%20outdating.svg)

How to read this chart:

- If `X → Y`, it means that `X` is better in every possible way than `Y`.
- If `X → Y → Z`, it means that:

  - `X` is better in every possible way than `Y`
  - `Y` is better in every possible way than `Z` *and*
  - `X` is *also* better in every possible way than `Z` (this is necessary to make the chart readable, or you get something completely unreadable like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WLdM3.jpg)).
- If an item is not in the diagram at all, then it's neither better or worse than any other item, so... just don't sell it.
- In the SNES version of Final Fantasy 6, [the Evade stat on armor is completely useless (the game uses magic evasion for everything)](http://finalfantasy.wikia.com/wiki/Evade_bug). The grey dashed arrow between Red Cap and Green Beret is SNES only; if you are playing the GBA version (or a version that patched this bug), ignore it.

---

Here's the same data for weapons with the very same caveats:

> [image: Weapon hierarchy]
>
> [**Click here for the bigger, searchable version**](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/1164414/SO/FF6%20weapon%20outdating.svg)

Comment: For those not in-the-know, the Cursed Shield (the worst item in this chart) can be turned into the Paladin's Shield (the best item on this chart). While not everyone is willing to spend the time to do so, it's the only way to get the Paladin's Shield, so don't immediately dump your Cursed Shield based on what you see on the chart!

Comment: @PanicBomb I am considering removing those two from the chart altogether...

Comment: The searchable versions of the charts have 404'd. Is there a mirror for these available?